# Should I Get the Minecraft Server in an EXE or JAR?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, windows

I'm running Windows 8, and I'm wondering if I should download the Minecraft server in an EXE program or a JAR file. I heard that with a JAR you can customize the amount of RAM you wish to give to a server. I have 8 GB of RAM. What would be the best way to get the best performance?

Answer (score 4):

You said in your post that you wanted the best performance. Because of this, I would recommend that you get the .jar file. It allows you to customize the amount of RAM the server has, allowing you to tweak it to your heart's content.

---

You will also be allowed to use the following switches:
`-d64` If your computer has a 64-bit architecture and you want to take advantage of that.
`nogui` if you don't want the graphical interface.
`-o true/false` to set the online/offline mode.
`--port` to choose which port you want to use.
`--world` to change the directory the world is in.
`--bonusChest` to enable the spawning of bonus chests in the world.
`-Xmx####M` or `-Xmx##G` to set the maximum java heap size (basically adding more RAM).
`--demo`, which changes the following properties in server.properties:

```
Seed          => -343522682 (a hash of "North Carolina")
Game Mode     => Survival
Map Features  => Enabled
Hardcode Mode => Disabled
World Type    => DEFAULT
```

In addition to the switches listed above, you can pretty much add any Java switch for ultimate tweaking.

---

To implement these, you would make a Windows batch script similar to this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /D %~dp0
JAVA -Xmx2048M -d64 -jar Minecraft_server.jar  -o true nogui
```

This would start the server without a graphical interface, with whitelist set to true, and with 2 gigabytes of memory to start out with.

Comment: How would I add these parameters? Could you provide an example of the run batch code with these features added?

Comment: @Tristan Added to answer

Comment: What code would give me the best possible performance? I'm on 64 bit architecture and 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Are you launching the client on the same computer?

Comment: Yes I am! Would that slow down the server a lot?

Comment: No, it just means you have to give your server less RAM so that your client doesn't suffer. But that's okay, since this is vanilla and you don't need much RAM anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see. So what code would give me the best possible performance?

Comment: `JAVA -jar Minecraft_server.jar nogui -d64 -Xmx2048M`

Comment: @JeffreyLin The order of the startup parameters matter, everything before `-jar Minecraft_server.jar` is passed to java, and should contain `-xm####` and -d64, while the other arguments to after it

Comment: @JeffreyLin Did you mean to post the `nogui` part outside the code blocks? Outside that the command now works as intended.

Comment: @ferrybig No, that has been fixed too.